# How to view all the list that can be viewed by update-alternatives?

Tags: bash, terminal, data, shell-builtin, qnap

[image: update-alternatives]

Tabbing gives me `ls` data but i want something to be shown like x-session-manager , x-terminal-emulator and so on. How can i get list what can i set?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Please, don't [post screenshots of console output](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4086/psa-please-dont-post-images-of-text), they are often difficult to read and won't be found by users googling for the same problem. In addition, contributors trying to help have to type-copy commands when trying to reproduce your approach. Instead, copy-and-paste the console text using proper [formatting](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help).

Answer (score 4):

Using `update-alternatives` itself, you can list all alternatives and show their current state by running

```
update-alternatives --get-selections
```

Alternatives are represented by symlinks in `/etc/alternatives`, so listing the files there will also show all available alternatives (but that’s technically relying on the implementation).

Comment: Ok I will try it